# Autonomous Clicker Murguu Not Working On Lubuntu as of 16.04

Tags: lubuntu

As of my upgrade from Lubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, an autonomous clicking software I use to play video games no longer works. Software can be found here - http://www.murguu.com/. It's a straight forward process to use normally. Download, unpackage, run the executable, and it would open. However, it doesn't work no matter what I do now. Does anybody know any backdoor ways I can try to get it working again? I'm pretty intermediate as far as skills are concerned with Ubuntu code, so I figured my best bet was to ask and see if anybody had any ideas.
I did uname -a to help provide this information, if necessary. 4.4.0-36-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 18:01:55 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
I have downloaded and am trying to use the 64bit version of the software. It just doesn't work. I have rheumatoid arthritis so it makes certain tasks much easier to perform where "continuously clicking" at a quick rate is concerned.
If any additional information is needed, or any help you can afford, let me know please. I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

(as a PS, if anybody knows of a similar software I can use on Lubuntu, I'd gladly look into some of those as well, if you can provide steps for installation and use. Preferably more easily used, user friendly types.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tons of research I determined that my shared libs where out of date or something to that effect. After running the following:

> sudo apt-get install libqtgui4

It installed the needed pieces that were preventing the software from running. It works perfectly now. I hope this may help any one who views this in the future. Thanks.